# Problems connecting to database

Tags: oracle, recovery

I have a user experiencing problems with mounting/contacted a database. I work in infrastructure so very very little knowledge on db's -- guess I was first/only port of call, so any advice would be  greatly appreciated. I have pasted what he has tried and my extremely basic suggestions :)

**Initial error reported:**

```
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors[oracle@*********** ~]$ sqlplus spsystem/reganam
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Jul 4 07:08:41 2019
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle. All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Enter user-name:

And when entering as sydba

SQL> select * from all_users;
select * from all_users
 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only
```

Quick search on these errors suggested a recovery of the database was needed and for the user to run the following from the SQL> prompt:

```
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE Instance started
SQL> recover database
Media recovery complete
SQL> alter database open;
Database altered
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

**This was attempted and failed**

Total System Global Area 3206836224 bytes
Fixed Size 2257520 bytes
Variable Size 771755408 bytes
Database Buffers 2415919104 bytes
Redo Buffers 16904192 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL> recover database
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01114: IO error writing block to file 2 (block # 1)
ORA-01110: data file 2: '/oracle/oradata/ora112/sysaux01.dbf'
ORA-27072: File I/O error
Linux-x86_64 Error: 5: Input/output error
Additional information: 4
Additional information: 1
Additional information: -1
```

There are no disk issues and filesystems are healthy (size & condition) and nothing that I can garner from OS logs or that I can fully understand from trace logs?

Comment: Running commands you don't really understand based on a quick search, or on advice you receive here or elsewhere on the internet, has a fairly good chance of making the situation worse *8-) So be careful... It does appear to be a disk issue though - as it's effectively reporting a bad block.

Comment: Perhaps that drive has run out of space.